# Changing the Search Results page to use 1 column layout in Magento2

Tags: magento2, layout

As far as I can tell Magento2 is not working as expected here.

In `/Magento_CatalogSearch/layout/` I have 4 XML files:

```
catalogsearch_advanced_index.xml
catalogsearch_advanced_results.xml
catalogsearch_result_index.xml
default.xml
```

In the top of each of these files I have the following line:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

Notice it says `layout="1column"`. I have cleared caches, I have re-indexed.

Despite all of this my search results page is still using `2columns-left`.

## My search results page is using `2columns-left` as its template file. How do I change this so my search results page is using `1column`?

Here is the full contents of `catalogsearch_result_index.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="page-products"/>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result" name="search.result" template="result.phtml" cacheable="false">
                <block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct" name="search_result_list" template="product/list.phtml" cacheable="false">
                    <arguments>
                        <!-- If argument's position depends on image size changeable in VDE:
                        positions:list-secondary,grid-secondary,list-actions,grid-actions,list-primary,grid-primary
                    -->
                        <argument name="positioned" xsi:type="string">positions:list-secondary</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="product/list/toolbar.phtml" cacheable="false">
                        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager" cacheable="false"/>
                    </block>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                    </action>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as="default"/>
                    </block>
                </block>
                <action method="setListOrders"/>
                <action method="setListModes"/>
                <action method="setListCollection"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Have you clear cache?

Comment: several times, and ive re-indexed

Comment: plz show your catalogsearch_result_index.xml file content. catalogsearch_result_index.xml is responsible for result page.

Comment: This file from theme or core module files?

Comment: @Rakesh done that - I havent changed this file much tbh

Comment: I copied this file from the core into my own module

Comment: have you working above code otherwise i will post working answer

Comment: please post working answer

Comment: When you load the search page what layout class has been added to the body, is it still 2columns-left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `catalogsearch_result_index.xml` use
`<update handle="1column"/>` after `<layout>` start.

So it should be like this

```
<body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd"> 
<update handle="1column"/>........your other codes
```

**Clear cache, deploy static files and check**

Comment: when you put `<layout xmlns:xsi="...` did you mean to put `<body xmlns:xsi="...` or are you suggesting that I should change `body` to `layout`?

Comment: Sorry that should be `body`. That was a typo mistake! I update my answer.. Let me know if it works or not

Comment: ok, putting `<update handle="1column">` directly after the `<body>` tag results in the page being completely blank?

Comment: You forgot the closing `/` @jimmery

Comment: Has this been the correct answer? If so, take your time, and accept! Help others to find answers quickly trough that.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me, but in v2.1.2 it's `<layout>` instead of `<body>`.

Comment: How do you use 1-column layout only for "no results" and keep 2-column for when there are results?

Comment: Does not work in 2.4.2

Answer (score 12):

You have to just add below file inside `app/design/frontend/{Package}/{themename}/Magento_CatalogSearch/`
content for catalogsearch_result_index.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    
    </page>
```

Flush the cache `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: plz check using above working code.

Comment: this is what I already have, as stated in my question - and it doesnt work

Comment: This works for Magento 2.4.2, hint: make sure that you are using `1column` not `1-column`

Answer (score 2):

I'm putting this here since it essentially provides the intended result, even though it doesn't do it the perfect way. Changing the layout attribute or using a update handle (mentioned in previous examples) of Magento_CatalogSearch/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml did not actually change the layout of the page as you can confirm by checking the body class. I would love to know why this isn't working since the same approach works in other modules. It could be something on my installation, but judging by the other responses here it could be something else.

If you target the Main Sidebar you can essentially achieve the desired 1column layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sidebar.main" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

My page element layout attribute is set to "1column" here, but through testing it is being ignored.