# Magento2 not picking up module's Block

Tags: magento2, fatal-error

I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getPrice() on null in /home/.../public_html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Shipping/Price.php on line 71
```

So, after reading [this solution here](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/1017) I altered this file:

```
/app/design/frontend/Package/Theme/Magento_Checkout/Block/Shipping/Price.php
```

However, I still keep getting the same error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getPrice() on null in /home/.../public_html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Shipping/Price.php on line 71
```

Which makes me think that Magento2 is ignoring my `Block` in `Magento_Checkout`, and defaulting back to Magento2's own core code.

How can I solve this issue (without editing the core code).

Is there something I need to do to register this Block?

---

Before I get asked:

I have deployed:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

I have re-indexed:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

I have cleared the cache:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

And Magento 2 is in the painfully slow developer mode.

I have made alterations to the view files in `/app/design/frontend/Package/Theme/Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/templates/...` and these have all worked fine. They are not being ignored, only `/app/design/frontend/Package/Theme/Magento_Checkout/Block` is being ignored.

---

I think [my problem here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112143/changing-the-search-results-page-to-use-1-column-layout-in-magento2) might be related, I have made changes to XML Layout for `Magento_CatalogSearch` but these changes are being ignored, and the default XML Layout is being used instead.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I'm not sure why you were downvoted? I'm upvoting as it seems like a well-considered question and you've posted many avenues you investigated.

Comment: Sorry i did it downvote. basically it is a mistake. i want to upvote but click on a wrong place

Comment: thanks for fixing that, was getting worried that me or my question was generating some hate for some unknown reason :)

Comment: I have the same problem, any news? :/

Comment: https://mage2.pro/t/topic/1017 ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but to get ridden of the fatal error in a clean way you can override the template with:

```
<?php
    // app/design/My/Theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/shipping/price.phtml

    if( $block->getShippingRate() )
        echo $block->getShippingPrice();
?>
```